# Map two columns to one field using parsing with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an object (Limit) that contains two fields (Low, High) with type ParsedValue.
ParsedValue has:

```
constructor (double, string);
method string ToString();
```

Each ParsedValue has it's value:double and unit:string and represents some measurement with a unit.

I want to have a table with fields:

```
low:double
high:double
unit:string
```

So when selecting Limit object I need to fill Low field with new ParsedValue(low, unit) and High field with new ParsedValue(high, unit). When inserting Limit object to the database, it should insert low=Low.Value, high=High.Value, unit=Low.Unit

How can I do that using Fluent NHibernate?

Comment: Why not just make columns for each value? Are you forced to use an existing legacy schema?

Comment: That's because they will always have the same unit.

Comment: Non sequiturs aside... then why even persist the unit?  I don't understand the insistence on persisting this data as a string at all.

Comment: ParsedValue is like: 2V, 3A, 25.3M etc. Limit is actually the range between two ParsedValues like 2V-10V. Of course, unit is always the same in the context of each Limit, but there could be some limits with different unit.

Comment: So use 2 or 3 columns, eg "2V-10V" = 2|10|V, "3A" = 3|A.  If you're trying to stick to 3rd normal form there's no reason to dump things into strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extending Brook's Comment:

assuming following classes

```
class LimitHolder
{
    public Limit Limit { get; set; }
}

class Limit
{
    public Limit(ParsedValue low, ParsedValue high)
    {
        Low = low;
        High = high;
    }

    public virtual ParsedValue Low { get; private set; }
    public virtual ParsedValue High { get; private set; }
}

class ParsedValue
{
    public ParsedValue(double value, string unit)
    {
        Value = value;
        Unit = unit;
    }
    public virtual double Value { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Unit { get; private set; }
}
```

the mapping

```
class LimitHolderMap : ClassMap<LimitHolder>
{
    public LimitHolderMap()
    {
        Map(lh => lh.Limit).CustomType<LimitUserType>();
    }
}

class LimitUserType : ImmutableUserType
{
    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var str = (string)NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return null;
        else
        {
            var splitted = str.Split('|');
            return new Limit(
                new ParsedValue(double.Parse(splitted[0]), splitted[2]),
                new ParsedValue(double.Parse(splitted[1]), splitted[2]));
        }
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        var limit = value as Limit;
        if (limit == null)
            NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
        else
        {
            var str = string.Concat(limit.Low.Value, '|', limit.High.Value, '|', limit.Low.Unit);
            NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, str, index);
        }
    }

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(Limit); }
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return new [] { SqlTypeFactory.GetString(100) }; }
    }
}
```

ImmutableUserType is my implementation of IUserType for immutable types. I can post the code if needed.

this would save the Limit in the same Table as the holder of it